# The relationship between the two statistical mechanical definitions of entropy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, definition

It seems like similar questions have been asked here; hopefully my question is not a duplicate.

I am reading my textbook on the statistical mechanical definitions of entropy, and I am very confused by the two different derivations of entropy using either $W$ and $\Omega$. For a $NVE$ ensemble, we know that $S=k_B\ln W$, where $W$ is the number of ways of having $a_1$ systems in state 1, $a_2$ systems in state 2, etc.  However, it is also true that if the degeneracy associated with the energy $E$ is $\Omega(E)$, then $S=k_B\ln\Omega$. Does this mean that $W=\Omega$?

I find it hard to believe that two totally different concepts actually share the same numerical value. The book also talked about the difference between the entropy of an ensemble ($S_\text{ensemble}$) and the entropy of a system ($S_\text{system}$). Am I confusing the two different quantities?

Comment: definition of statistical ensemble: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_ensemble_(mathematical_physics)

Comment: and of degeneracy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_energy_levels

Comment: I both cases $W$ or $\Omega$ is is the number of microstates consistent with the given macrostate.